# Android drawable: state_selected working, superseding state_pressed?

Tags: android, android-drawable

Newbie in Android.

I have the following defined in res/drawable/ for a button in a menu that's defined in style.xml

```
<style name="menu_icon">
    <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">@dimen/menu_item_height</item>
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/menu_item_bg_sel</item>
</style>
```

Now, menu_item_bg_sel in drawable has two different color gradients for 2 states that I am interested in- pressed and selected.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true">
     <layer-list>          
        <item>
            <shape>
                 <gradient android:angle="180"
                 android:endColor="@color/background_menu_gray_selected2" 
                           android:centerColor="@color/background_menu_gray_selected1" 
                           android:startColor="@color/background_menu_gray_selected" />
            </shape>
        </item>
    </layer-list>
   </item>
   <item android:state_selected="true">
<layer-list>          
        <item>
            <shape>
                 <gradient  android:angle="180" android:endColor="@color/background_menu_home2" 
                            android:centerColor="@color/background_menu_home1" 
                            android:startColor="@color/background_menu_home" />
            </shape>
        </item>
    </layer-list>
   </item>
<item android:drawable="@color/transparent"/>
```

However, when I press the button (that transient state) the button still creates the gradient taking   colors from the selected_state only.

What am I doing wrong? Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

`state_selected` is commonly used when navigating using d-pads or maybe a pen like what Samsung Notes so I suggest not to use `state_selected` since when you press automatically it will be selected or gain focus although selected and focus are kind or different. I suggest to use state_pressed, state_focused and state_hovered instead.

For more info click [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#StateList)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code. You can copy paste this code into one drawable file. You can assign different drawable files or define shapes in this file itself for the different states.I have assigned a drawable file for the focused state as an example.

simple_button_states.xml

```
   <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <item
            android:state_focused="true"
            android:drawable="@drawable/rounded_edittext_focused"
            />
        <!--pressed -->
        <item
            android:state_pressed="true" />

        <!--selected -->
        <item
            android:state_selected="true" />

        <!-- focused -->
        <item
            android:drawable="@drawable/rounded_edittext_unfocused"/>


    </selector>

round_edittext_focused.xml



<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    >
    <solid android:color="#FFFFFF" />

    <stroke
        android:width="2dp"
        android:color="@color/CornflowerBlue" />
    <corners
        android:topLeftRadius="4dp"
        android:topRightRadius="4dp"
        android:bottomLeftRadius="4dp"
        android:bottomRightRadius="4dp"

        />
</shape>
```

Finally assign the background of the actual button as the drawable file that you have declared above.

```
   <Button
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:background="@drawable/simple_button_states"
        />
```

Hope this helps